# Is it Possible to have a different screen scale resolution for each workspace?

Tags: display-resolution, workspaces, 4k-monitor, scale-mode

I ask because I own a 4k large monitor and its a pain in the ass having to always change the resolution when Apps don't scale well to 4k e.g Steam, Spotify, Runescape(osrs) and other.

So what I would like know if its possible to have my main workspace remain at 4k and have the other change to e.g 1920x1080, 1600x900 1368x768.
In essence a different resolution for each workspace.

Thank You.

Comment: Scaling and resolution isn't the same. Always select the native resolution but do change the scaling if it needs to be. And no, even if changing the resolution was the solution, you can't have different ones for workspaces.

Comment: This can be implemented as Python script, but sadly I don't have time and you probably don't wanna wait till late December. I'll contact couple people, maybe they'll be willing to implement something like that.

Comment: Very relevant issue. My workaround is to run my system in a lower resolution, unfortunatelly